# onPushButtonClick code redirects to another Widget/Class(mainWindow.cpp)

Tags: c++, qt

I am wondering how I can redirect my code into mainWindow.cpp where my main program will be located after the user clicks on the "login" button(onPushButtonClick). Currently when the user pushes the button it opens the second widget but it stays at the smaller size equivalent to the login window, so how can I redirect the code in mainWindow UI so after they click "login" it opens a new window at the correct size as my MainWindow.ui.

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ2QP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much help this will be but personally I would create a new widget for the login page, so that mainwindow.ui stays as the main. This would than be easier in theory. Sorry if this is no help.

Comment: I believe that is what I did as you can see the login.cpp and also the mainWindow.cpp, but how do I go about telling the code to start running mainWindow.cpp after they push the button?

Comment: With out seeing your code, you would go to your login.ui and right click on your login button and go to slot, inside the slot you need to execute the mainwindow. Recommend watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VigUMAfE2q4